# How can I check if a Java Object is a String?

Tags: java, string, object

How can I check if an object is of type string?

Comment: `obj instanceof String`?

Comment: The better question is: why are you designing code that needs to check?  That's usually a bad sign.  Polymorphism should be the thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if(object instanceof String)
{
    // Do Stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
Integer myInt = 3;
if (myInt instanceof String)
    System.out.println("It's a String!");
else
    System.out.println("Not a String :(");
```

Comment: This is a bad example, as the String is already declared as String, and not as Object (or other super class of String).

Comment: I thought more of declaring an Object, because declaring an Integer or a String makes this a compile time decision. Only for a super class of String (which neither Integer nor String are) this is a runtime decision. But anyway, I removed my down vote.

Answer (score 3):

By using the `instanceof` operator in java:

```
if(object instanceof String){
    System.out.println("String object");
    // continue your code here
}
else{
     System.out.println("it is not a String");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   if( obj instanceof String ) {}
```

is a way to check for the object you got is of String