# check if an object is string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, instanceof

I was following a tutorial that suggested to check if an object is string and not empty as the following:

```
var s = "text here";
if ( s && s.charAt && s.charAt(0))
```

it is said that if s is string then it has a method charAt and then the last component will check if the string is empty or not.

I tried to test it with the other available methods like ( `typeof` and `instanceof` ) using some of the [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059147/check-if-a-variable-is-a-string)  and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583217/how-can-i-check-if-a-java-object-is-a-string)  and [here too !!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-do-you-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript)

so I decided to test it in Js Bin : [jsbin code here](http://jsbin.com/bovihumo/1/edit) as follow:

```
var string1 = "text here";
var string2 = "";


alert("string1  is " + typeof string1);
alert("string2  is " + typeof string2);


//part1- this will succeed and show it is string
if(string1 && string1.charAt){
  alert( "part1- string1 is string");
}else{
  alert("part1- string1 is not string ");
}


//part2- this will show that it is not string
if(string2 && string2.charAt ){
  alert( "part2- string2 is string");
}else{
  alert("part2- string2 is not string ");
}



//part3 a - this also fails !!
if(string2 instanceof String){  
  alert("part3a- string2 is really a string");
}else{
  alert("part3a- failed instanceof check !!");
}

//part3 b- this also fails !!
//i tested to write the String with small 's' => string
// but then no alert will excute !!
if(string2 instanceof string){  
  alert("part3b- string2 is really a string");
}else{
  alert("part3b- failed instanceof check !!");
}
```

Now my questions are :

1- why does the check for string fails when the string is empty using the `string2.charAt` ???

2- why does the `instanceof` check failed??

Comment: `if(string2.charAt)` is only checking if method is defined, an empty string is still a string so will return true

Comment: @charlietfl plz refere to answer of adeneo where he said "A simple string is not an object, it's a primary data type, and has no prototype, as opposed to a String object created with new String."

Comment: So empty string defind as literal will not return true if checked for the charAt function presence

Comment: @stackunderflow It would, if using the code provided. (Because `"".charAt(0) -> "" -> false-y`. The thing that would *not* work is `"" instanceof String && ..`, because it is a *string* value, not a *String* object.

Comment: @user2864740 string created like this (var s ="";) will not have a `cahrAt` function at all !!

Comment: @stackunderflow Sure it will [have a `charAt` method] - *try it*. This is because a *string* will be promoted to a *String* when a method is invoked upon it.

Comment: @user2864740 cool info regarding (string promotion) thanks buddy

Comment: @stackunderflow following your logic you could never do `'somestring'.charAt(n)`

Comment: @charlietfl you are right. but that was misonception corrected by user2864740, when he said that string literals will be promoted to String object.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*string values* are not *String objects* (which is why the instanceof fails)<sup>2</sup>.

To cover both cases using "type-checking" it would be `typeof x === "string" || x instanceof String`; the first only matches *strings* and the latter matches *Strings*.

The tutorial assumes that [only] String objects - or string values which are promoted<sup>1</sup> - have a `charAt` method and so uses ["duck-typing"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). If the method does exist, then it is called. If `charAt` is used out-of-bounds then an empty string "", which is a false-y value, is returned.

The tutorial code would also accept a string of "\0", while `s && s.length` would not - but it would also "work" on arrays (or jQuery objects, etc). Personally, I *trust* the caller to provide the allowed values/types and use as little "type-checking" or special-casing as possible.

---

<sup>1</sup> For primitive values of string, number, and boolean there is a corresponding object type of String, Number, and Boolean, respectively. When `x.property` is used on one of these primitive values the effect is `ToObject(x).property` - hence the "promotion". This is discussed in [ES5: 9.9 - ToObject](http://es5.github.io/#x9.9).

Neither the null or undefined values have corresponding objects (or methods). Functions are already objects but have a historically different, and useful, `typeof` result.

<sup>2</sup> See [ES5: 8 - Types](http://es5.github.io/#x8-toc) for the different types of values. The String Type, eg., represents a *string* value.

Answer (score 7):

> 1- Why does the check for string fails when the string is empty using the string2.charAt?

The following expression evaluates to false because the first condition fails:

```
var string2 = "";
if (string2 && string2.charAt) { console.log("doesn't output"); }
```

That second line is basically equivalent to:

```
if (false && true) { console.log("doesn't output"); }
```

So for example:

```
if (string2) { console.log("this doesn't output since string2 == false"); }
if (string2.charAt) { console.log('this outputs'); }
```

> 2- Why does the instanceof check fail?

This fails because, in javascript, string can be literals or objects. For example:

```
var myString = new String("asdf");
myString instanceof String; // true
```

However:

```
var myLiteralString = "asdf";
myLiteralString instanceof String; // false
```

You can reliably tell if it's a string by checking both the type and the `instanceof`:

```
str instanceof String || typeof str === "string";
```

Comment: you missed something . my question was not putting parameter zero . it is actually without brackets. `if(string1 && string1.charAt){`